# Вычислить количество феноменов любви треугольников

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

> Spichonees (составленное имя) живут в стране Spichland, где нет пола. Spichonees - большие любовники, поэтому каждый Spichonee любит любого другого Spichonee. К сожалению, иногда бывают ситуации, когда Spichonee A любит Spichonee B, Spichonee B любит Spichonee C и Spichonee C любит Spichonee A. Это явление называется любовным треугольником.
>
> задача
> Ваша задача - реализовать функцию getLoveTrianglesCount, которая вычисляет количество феноменов любви треугольников. Функция принимает массив целых чисел как единственный параметр. Целое число k на n-ом месте означает, что n-ый Spichonee любит kth Spichonee.

```html
                               // 1  2  3  Spichonees
  let count = getLoveTrianglesCount([2, 3, 1]);
  console.log(count); // 1
  /**
    1st Spichonee loves 2nd Spichonee.
    2nd Spichonee loves 3rd Spichonee.
    3rd Spichonee love 1st Spichonee.
    There is love triangle.
  */
```

Ниже то что я сделал, но большая часть тестов не проходит

```html
function getLoveTrianglesCount(preferences = []) {
  // your implementation
  let length = preferences.length; 
  let count = 0;  
  for (let i = 0; i<length; i++) { 
    let lover = preferences[preferences[i]];
    console.log(lover + '___' + preferences[i]) 
    if (lover === i+1) {      
      count++; 
      }
     }
     if (count%2) { 
       return (count); 
      }
       return count/2; 
};
console.log(getLoveTrianglesCount([6, 14, 12, 21, 3, 20, 7, 15, 16, 16, 14, 4, 11, 13, 18, 2, 1, 8, 3, 1, 121]));
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Finding all cycles in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/546655/2881286)

Comment: Не стоит вандализировать собственные вопросы.

Comment: Шикарная текстовка вопроса, апвоут. PS Слово придумалось: трелюбовники

Comment: `но большая часть тестов не проходит` - а можете тесты куда-нить выложить чтоб сверяться?

Comment: Не стоит вандализировать вопрос. @bara GAMES вы можете пояснить, зачем вы это делаете?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу о замене текста вопроса на бессмыслицу - таки зачем? =)

Answer (score 3):

Делаем **три** шага, а не два. Количество циклов втрое меньше числа участвующих. 
Каждый шаг проверяем зацикленность на себя.

(Ещё стоит проверять на валидность числа в массиве)

[В развернутом виде:](https://ideone.com/wkKOCo)

```
function getLoveTrianglesCount(preferences = []) {
  // your implementation
  let length = preferences.length; 
  let count = 0;  
  for (let i = 0; i<length; i++) { 
      let next = preferences[i] - 1;
      if (next == i) continue;
      let nextnext = preferences[next] - 1;
      if (next == nextnext) continue;
      let nextnextnext = preferences[nextnext] - 1;
      if (nextnextnext == nextnext) continue;
      if (nextnextnext == i) {
          count++;
      }
   }
   return count / 3;
}

print(getLoveTrianglesCount([5,5,2,3,3]));
print(getLoveTrianglesCount([4,3,3,6,6,1]));
print(getLoveTrianglesCount([4,3,3,6,8,1,5,7]));
```

> 1 1 2

Answer (score 2):

Если я все правильно понял, а именно:

1. Каждый элемент массива - это Spichonee
2. Нужно найти в массиве множества вида - 3,4,5 или 12,13,14 и т.д.
3. Посчитать их кол-во.

То как вариант - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/MqVBzd

```
const getLoveTrianglesCount = arrSpichonees => [...new Set(arrSpichonees.filter(e => e && arrSpichonees.includes(e+1) && arrSpichonees.includes(e+2)))].length;
```

```js
const getLoveTrianglesCount = arrSpichonees =>
[...new Set(arrSpichonees.filter(e => e && arrSpichonees.includes(e+1) && arrSpichonees.includes(e+2)))].length;
console.log(getLoveTrianglesCount([6, 14, 12, 21, 3, 20, 7, 15, 16, 16, 14, 4, 11, 13, 18, 2, 1, 8, 3, 1, 121]));
```

Вообще по идее - каждый Spichonee должен быть один, поэтому наверное уникальным массив лучше делать сразу. =>

`const getLoveTrianglesCount = arrSpichonees => [...new Set(arrSpichonees)].filter(e => e && arrSpichonees.includes(e+1) && arrSpichonees.includes(e+2)).length;`

Comment: надо не множества найти, а такие тройки что на `N`-й позиции будет число `M`, на позиции `M` будет число `K`, а на позиции `K` будет число `N`

Comment: @teran,  Вы точно понимаете что такое множество? Вот для начала хотя бы https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: Для понимания в принципе хватает и первого абзаца

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, ваша задача "в лоб" решается так (полагаем, что выходные данные не нуждаются в валидации):

```js
function findCount(data){
   var result = 0;
   data.unshift(0);
   
   for(let a = 1; a < data.length; a++){
       let b = data[a];
       let c = data[b];
       
       result += a == data[c];
   }
   return result/3;
}

let count = findCount([2, 3, 1, 5,6,4]);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

В одну строку:

```
findCount=data=>data.filter((value,index,array)=>array[array[value-1]-1]==index+1).length/3;
```